# How can I add new Conn Types (MYSQL) to Airflow 2.0 Astronomer?

Tags: mysql-connector, airflow-2.x

I'm learning Apache Airflow 2.0 astronomer and I was creating a new "Connection" but in "Conn Type" there are just a few options, for example I want to add a MySQL connection but there isn't that option. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noXxw.png)

Comment: Its modular, you can use pip or other installer based on your OS. Refer [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html). ```pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql```

Comment: Also, you can refer to [demo](https://youtu.be/4ajqOlHCBCQ). Though its for snowflake connector, but I believe it would be relevant as idea is same.

Comment: can you make a video tutorial, for mysql conector ..? please

Comment: Sure I'll look in it. Also if you can update the other video with same comment, it will help me remember.

Comment: I have added this as an answer, please refer same.

Answer (score 0):

Refer for [video](https://youtu.be/kDf6AWAtzSI) showing below steps.

Steps for installing apache airflow mysql provider.

```
1) sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel

2) pip install mysqlclient

3) pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

For mysql install [refer](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/).

For airflow mysql provider install [refer](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html).

Above steps are for Linux environment (redhat based).
Step-1 is needed if there is no mysql configuration on the underlying OS. The `pip install mysqlclient` fails without it.

I did not specifically installed `mysql-connector-python`, per [requirements](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html#requirements) of airflow mysql provider, because it gets installed  as part of `step-1: sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`. Can be checked via command `pip list|grep mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default all the connection types are not available. you may need to install the airflow MySQL provider in the container. You can add the below command in your Dockerfile to install the MySQL provider.

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-mysql
```

After this, you should be able to see the MySQL conn type.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/index.html